# How I can print string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to print a string in following manner 'abc',21,'email' in javascript how can I do. below is my code.

```
var data = [];
data.push('abc');
data.push(21);    
data.push('email');
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a function to quote a string:

```
function quote(s) {
  return typeof s === 'string' ? "'"+s+"'" : s;
}
```

Now map your array and paste the elements together with a comma:

```
data . map(quote) . join(',')
```

Since joining with a comma is the default way to convert an array into a string, you might be able to get away without the `join` in some situations:

```
alert (data . map(quote));
```

since `alert` converts its parameter into a string. Same with

```
element.textContent = data . map(quote);
```

Answer (score 1):

if data is an array defined as

```
var data = [];
data.push('abc');
data.push(21);    
data.push('email');
```

the use [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method of array to join (concatenate) the values by specifying the separator

try

```
alert( "'" + data.join("','") + "'" );
```

or

```
console.log( "'" + data.join("','") + "'" );
```

or simply

```
var value =  "'" + data.join("','") + "'" ;
document.body.innerHTML += value;
```

Comment: Won't that put quotes around the `21`?

Comment: @torazaburo yes it will, my bad, i missed this specific detail.

Answer (score -1):

Now `data = ['abc', 21, 'email'];`

So we can use `forEach` function

```
var myString = '';

data.forEach(function(value, index){
   myString += typeof value === 'string' ? "'" + value + "'" : value;
   if(index < data.length - 1) myString += ', ';
});

console.log(myString)
```

Shorter version:

```
myString = data.map(function(value){
   return typeof value === 'string' ? "'" + value + "'" : value;
}).join(', ');

console.log(myString);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LeoAref/ea5fa3de/

Comment: You should use prv instead of using an external variable myString. Also, won't this put an extra comma at the end?

Comment: That's interesting to know why I got a negative?!

Comment: Since you're not mapping, you could just use `forEach`.

Comment: Ok now I use `forEach`, by the way, 'forEach` is more convenient, but both are the same!!!

Comment: Well, some people downvote answers if they're wrong. Anyway, you were actually on the right track with the use of `reduce` as you were doing before the edit. Instead of you having to declare your own variable (`myString`), reduce maintains this variable internally, passing it to the callback on each iteration of the loop as the first parameter, what you were calling `prv`.

Comment: Your most recent edit will not work because `forEach` returns nothing.

Comment: `map` and `forEach` are superficially similar, but they differ in what they **mean**--in other words, in their semantics. `forEach` simply executes some code for each element. The callback returns nothing, and `forEach` itself returns nothing.  `map` is used to transform an array. The callback returns the value to be used for that element, and `map` itself returns the transformed array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101053/discussion-between-muhammad-aref-and-torazaburo).